# Remove none values in this list using python

Tags: python

i want to remove None values in this list

```py
input= [(None, 'Ibrahimpatnam', 9440627084, None, 'Under Investigation'),
        (None, 'Ibrahimpatnam', 9440627084, None, 'Under Investigation')]
```

and get an output like

```py
['Ibrahimpatnam', 9440627084, 'Under Investigation', 'Ibrahimpatnam', 9440627084, 'Under Investigation']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the list (which contains tuples) and then iterate through each tuple. Check if each element of each tuple is `None` or not.

```py
a = [
    (None, "Ibrahimpatnam", 9_440_627_084, None, "Under Investigation"),
    (None, "Ibrahimpatnam", 9_440_627_084, None, "Under Investigation"),
]
b = [element for sub_tuple in a for element in sub_tuple if element is not None]
print(b)
```

and you get

> ['Ibrahimpatnam', 9440627084, 'Under Investigation', 'Ibrahimpatnam', 9440627084, 'Under Investigation']

Comment: @Hayat That's what the OP asked for, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah..Sure Didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input_= [(None, 'Ibrahimpatnam', 9440627084, None, 'Under Investigation'),
        (None, 'Ibrahimpatnam', 9440627084, None, 'Under Investigation')]
output = []
for each in input_:
    newList = list(filter(None,each))
    output = output+newList
print(output)
```

**Note:** Do not use `input` as the variable it is a reserved keyword in python. It's okay if you have just used it for this post.

Answer (score 0):

If you wnat to strip, then concatenate -- list comprehension works really cleanly here without losing readability:

```
import itertools
stripped_lists = [ [x for x in sublist if x] for sublist in input_ ]

print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(stripped_lists )))
```

output:

```
['Ibrahimpatnam', 9440627084, 'Under Investigation', 'Ibrahimpatnam', 9440627084, 'Under Investigation']
```

Alternatively, if you concatenate and then strip, this is nice and short:

```
print(list(x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(aa) if x))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, flatten the data using list comprehension and then use `filter()` method to filter out the None values. `filter()` method will return a filter object. So we'll have to use the `list()` method to convert it back to a list:

```
flat_input = [item for sublist in input for item in sublist]
output = list(filter(None, flat_input))
```

This is the shortest solution I can imagine. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

iterate the list then sub list if sub-list item is not None add to new list b

```
a = [
    (None, "Ibrahimpatnam", 9_440_627_084, None, "Under Investigation"),
    (None, "Ibrahimpatnam", 9_440_627_084, None, "Under Investigation"),
]
b=[]
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        if j:
            b.append(j)


print (b)
```